# How to build this responsive grid with css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmYWn.png)

```css
.wrapper-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr 0.5fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.wrapper-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(1){
  grid-column: 1/3
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 3/5
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(3){
  grid-column: 1/2
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(4){
  grid-column: 2/4
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(5){
  grid-column: 4/5
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

I trying to build this responsive grid whith html code below. When its without grid-gap, its ok, in first row images have same width and in second row too. But when i add grid-gap, second element in second row become a little bigger than his neighbours on left and right. I trying to use calc(), but its not work. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the middle element include a gap so its width is `gap + 1fr` unlike the other that are only `1fr`. try to change like below so that all the bottom elements will include one gap and 2fr thus they will be the same. The top ones will have `3fr + 2gap` and remain equal.

```css
.wrapper-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.wrapper-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(1){
  grid-column: 1/4
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 4/7
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(3){
  grid-column: 1/3
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(4){
  grid-column: 3/5
}
.wrapper-item:nth-child(5){
  grid-column: 5/7
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-grid">
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  </div>
</div>
```